# Нужна помощь с получением id сообщения в беседе vk

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Имеется код:

```
token_bot = 'token'
vk_session_bot = vk_api.VkApi(token = token_bot)
longpoll_bot = VkLongPoll(vk_session_bot)

res = vk_session_bot.method('messages.send', {'random_id' : 0, 'peer_ids': 2000000000 + 4, 'message' : 'TEST'})
print(res)
```

Пользуясь методом messages.send, отправляю сообщение в чат vk, но в массиве id сообщения всегда - 0

```
[{'peer_id': 2000000004, 'message_id': 0}]
```

ID сообщения мне нужен для дальнейшего редактирования сообщения. Подскажите, как получить ID ну или как отредактировать сообщение без него (по задумке сообщение должно содержать упоминание пользователей, а потом тут же редактироваться дабы пользователи получившие уведомление видели текст уведомления а не сообщение с упоминаниями)

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понял, проблема со стороны библиотеки vk_api. Она просто не возвращает значение conversation_message_id. Решение проблемы - отправлять get запрос с помощью библиотеки requests, и в ответе при переданном параметре peer_ids как раз таки будет conversation_message_id